# KotlinJsonAdapterFactory unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I am building an Android app in Kotlin, and I'm using Retrofit for the API calls, and I'm also using Moshi. But when building Moshi it says KotlinJsonAdapteryFactory - unresolved reference, and I can't use Moshi since it gives me an error in this line. Any idea of why is this happening?
These are my Moshi dependencies:

```
    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.12.0")
    kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.12.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.5.0"
```

and this is the code for building Moshi and Retrofit

```
 private val moshi: Moshi = Moshi.Builder().addLast(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
 val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(getLoggingHttpClient())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        .build()
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just update to kotlin version

```
implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.14.0")
```

https://github.com/square/moshi

Comment: Okay, It worked!